# regex to find the string with numbers or letters

Tags: regex

I have a requirement of a regular expression.

1-4 number or 1-4 letter combo (required)."letter" can be any letter Unicode or Latin-1.
Minimum 1 letter or number is required and the first number should not be 0.
So i wrote the following regex.

```
([1-9\p{L}]{1}[0-9\p{L}]{0,3})
```

Will this work fine?

Comment: provide some samples as well.

Comment: Did you test the regex?

Comment: Valid scenarios: 123A, A23,A2c1               Invalid scenarios: 0123a,0Aq2             I used http://www.regexr.com/ site to test the changes but it is not recognising \p{L}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems working, just add start `^` and end `$` anchors,

```
^[1-9\p{L}][0-9\p{L}]{0,3}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fE9wH8/2)

Comment: How you tested it? I added start and end patterns before posting also.

Comment: http://www.regexr.com/ is not workign but the second one is working.thanks for the help.